# Python Type Bug of List and Int?

Tags: python

I wanna read a list of number and sort them functionally, and here is the code:

```py
user_input = [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]
for i in user_input:
    if i == user_input[0]: list2 = [[i]]

    for j in list2:
        if user_input[i] - j[-1] == 1:
            j.append(user_input[i])
        else:
            list2.append(user_input[i])
print(list2)

#############################################
>>> 8 7 1 9 2 6 3 5 4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    if user_input[i] - j[-1] == 1:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I googled this problem and know that this problem happened when call int object with subscript, but when I run `print(type(user_input), type(j))` and both the result are `list`. I wonder why the error happened. Can someone explain me please:)

Comment: The issue is that later when you do `list2.append(user_input[i])`, you are appending an int and not a list

Answer (score 5):

its a bad idea to modify your list2 while iterate through them.
your list2 starts as a list of list, then you starts to insert int to it, which causes the problem...

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll think of other ways.